# Co-occurrence matrix using SAC?

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following data frame 'x'

```
id,item,volume
a,c1,2
a,c2,3
a,c3,2
a,c4,1
a,c5,4
b,c6,6
b,c1,2
b,c3,1
b,c2,6
b,c4,4
c,c2,5
c,c8,6
c,c9,2
d,c1,1
e,c3,7
e,c2,3
e,c1,2
e,c9,5
e,c4,1
f,c1,7
f,c3,1
```

The first column is the id of a customer, the second column is the id of an item that customer bought and the third column is the number of those items bought. I'm trying to create a co-occurrence matrix which is a square matrix with 8 rows and columns, 8 being the number of distinct items.

```
n = length(unique(x$cid))
```

Could this be done through a SAC paradigm? For every id, I need to update the above matrix by adding +1 for every combination. For example for user 'b' with items c1,c2,c3,c4,c6, the 1st row in the matrix for columns 2,3,4 & 6 should be incremented by 1 and so on for all users. I'm unable to cast it into this framework. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: While R questions are perfectly welcome here, I wonder if this requires more statistics experience than programming experience; have you seen the [stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)? Check the bit about picking which site to ask the question on .. if you think SO is fine, let me know and I'll delete my comment. If you think [stats.se] would be better, please flag your post for moderator attention and ask for a migration.

Comment: @sarnold I disagree, I think this is purely a question about rearranging data programmatically. I suspect the stats.SE folks would migrate it here.

Comment: To the OP, there are several aspects of your question that are unclear. You suggest you want the rows of your co-occurrence matrix to correspond to customers (id), but there are only 6 ids and you say you want an 8x8 matrix. Do you mean a 6x8 matrix? Also, should the entries of the matrix be 0/1, or the counts from the volume column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joran mentioned its kind of unclear what you really want. But If I understand correctly(probably not) I would like to propose an alternate route.  I think you want a matrix of items to items with numbers representing the number of times the items share a customer?

If so then:

```
library(igraph)
library(tnet)
id_item<-cbind(
i=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8),  #items
p=c(1,2,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8))  #customers
item_item<-projecting_tm(id_item, method="sum")
item_item <- tnet_igraph(item_item,type="weighted one-mode tnet")
itemmat<-get.adjacency(item_item,attr="weight")
itemmat  #8x8 martrix of items to items

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    0    2    1    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    2    0    1    1    2    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    2    0    0    0    1    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
#[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

If you need to take number of times the item was bought (volume) into account too then this is easily added into this code.

Comment: the final result is what I want. But can't get the packages to install on my version of ubuntu. Will poke around some more

Comment: hmm thats annoying.. hope you get it going!

Answer (score 1):

rehsape2 provides 'acast', which might be what you want:

```
> acast(x, id~item,value.var='volume')
  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c8 c9
a  2  3  2  1  4 NA NA NA
b  2  6  1  4 NA  6 NA NA
c NA  5 NA NA NA NA  6  2
d  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
e  2  3  7  1 NA NA NA  5
f  7 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA
```

reshape2::dcast produces a data frame, if that is more convenient.