# Counting pairs in R

Tags: r, count, interaction, key-pair

I have a dataset of 3 columns with Column 1 being ID(NOT UNIQUE) AND COLUMNS 2 AND 3 being a positive and negative value associated with the id respectively. I am new to R and just trying to figure out how to count the number of **pairs of values** associated with each id. The table and unique function is not helping since I have to count the pairs. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `interaction`. You also need to post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with data.table package

```
library(data.table)
tdata[, list(paircount = .N) , by = c("ID","COLUMN2","COLUMN3")]
```

EDIT:

Based on Michael's feedback, I may have misunderstood the question.

```
tdata[, list(paircount = nrow((unique(.SD)))), by = "ID"]
```

should get you what you need.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if DataScience wanted to do this, he or she would just used `table()`...

Comment: What's the difference between your method and this Arun's method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244685/count-every-possible-pair-of-values-in-a-column-grouped-by-multiple-columns  using setorder and setkey?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to count the number of unique pairs for each ID. As @BondedDust mentioned, use `interaction`:

```
df$pair <- with(df, interaction(COLUMN2, COLUMN3))
rowSums(xtabs(~ id + pair, df) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
unique(data[,c("ID", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3")])
```

Or, to have results groupes by ID:

```
by(data = data[,c("COLUMN2", "COLUMN3")],INDICES = data$ID, FUN = unique)
```