# Find co-occurrence of values in large data set

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a large data set with month, customer ID and store ID. There is one record per customer, per location, per month summarizing their activity at that location.

```
  Month  Customer ID Store
  Jan       1      A
  Jan       4      A
  Jan       2      A
  Jan       3      A    
  Feb       7      B
  Feb       2      B
  Feb       1      B
  Feb       12     B
  Mar       1      C
  Mar       11     C 
  Mar       3      C
  Mar       12     C
```

I'm interested in creating a matrix that shows the number of customers that each location shares with another. Like this:

```
      A        B         C
A     4        2         2     
B     2        4         2
C     2        2         4
```

For example, since customer visited Store A and then Store B in the next month, they would be added to the tally. I'm interested in number of shared customers, not number of visits.

I tried the sparse matrix approach in this thread([Creating co-occurrence matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix)), but the numbers returned don't match up for some reason I cannot understand.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
The original solution that I posted worked for your data. But your data has
the unusual property that no customer ever visited the same store in two different 
months. Presuming that would happen, a modification is needed.

What we need is a matrix of stores by customers that has 1 if the customer ever
visited the store and zero otherwise.   The original solution used
`M  = as.matrix(table(Dat$ID_Store, Dat$Customer))`
which gives how many different months the store was visited by each customer. With 
different data, these numbers might be more than one. We can fix that by using
`M = as.matrix(table(Dat$ID_Store, Dat$Customer) > 0)`
If you look at this matrix, it will say TRUE and FALSE,  but since TRUE=1 and FALSE=0
that will work just fine.  So the full corrected solution is:

```
M = as.matrix(table(Dat$ID_Store, Dat$Customer) > 0)
M %*% t(M)

    A B C
  A 4 2 2
  B 2 4 2
  C 2 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try this too:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- dcast(df,CustomerID~Store, length, value.var='Store')
#  CustomerID A B C
#1          1 1 1 1 
#2          2 1 1 0 # Customer 2 went to stores A,B but not to C
#3          3 1 0 1
#4          4 1 0 0
#5          7 0 1 0
#6         11 0 0 1
#7         12 0 1 1
crossprod(as.matrix(df[-1]))
#  A B C
#A 4 2 2
#B 2 4 2
#C 2 2 4
```

with library `arules`:

```
library(arules)
write('   Jan       1      A
          Jan       4      A
          Jan       2      A
          Jan       3      A    
          Feb       7      B
          Feb       2      B
          Feb       1      B
          Feb       12     B
          Mar       1      C
          Mar       11     C 
          Mar       3      C
          Mar       12     C', 'basket_single')
tr <- read.transactions("basket_single", format = "single", cols = c(2,3))
inspect(tr)
#    items   transactionID
#[1] {A,B,C} 1            
#[2] {C}     11           
#[3] {B,C}   12           
#[4] {A,B}   2            
#[5] {A,C}   3            
#[6] {A}     4            
#[7] {B}     7    
image(tr)
```

[image]

```
crossTable(tr, sort=TRUE)
#  A B C
#A 4 2 2
#B 2 4 2
#C 2 2 4
```

Comment: Hi Sandipan. Could the arules library also be used to calculate these customers' activity in the other locations. For example, if I had a column for "number of bath products purchased" and another for "number of outdoor products", could I sum the activity that occurred in the matrix we created originally? I.e. if customers belonging to Store A went to Store B, can we summarize their activity there?