# Co-occurrence matrix from nested list of words

Tags: python, pandas, list, matrix, networkx

I have a list of names like:

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

and a list of documents, that in each documents some of these names are mentioned.

```
document =[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'B', 'K'],['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Z']]
```

I would like to get an output as a matrix of co-occurrences like:

```
  A  B  C  D
A 0  2  1  1
B 2  0  2  1
C 1  2  0  1
D 1  1  1  0
```

There is a solution ([Creating co-occurrence matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix)) for this problem in R, but I couldn't do it in Python. I am thinking of doing it in Pandas, but yet no progress!

Comment: Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464861/how-can-i-convert-a-two-column-array-to-a-matrix-with-counts-of-occurences/64464941#64464941) question.  Added a much simpler [graph based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64597418/9698684)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Obviously this can be extended for your purposes, but it performs the general operation in mind:

```
import math

for a in 'ABCD':
    for b in 'ABCD':
        count = 0

        for x in document:
            if a != b:
                if a in x and b in x:
                    count += 1

            else:
                n = x.count(a)
                if n >= 2:
                    count += math.factorial(n)/math.factorial(n - 2)/2

        print '{} x {} = {}'.format(a, b, count)
```

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to use the constructor 
`csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])` from [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) where `data`, `row_ind` and `col_ind` satisfy the
            relationship `a[row_ind[k], col_ind[k]] = data[k]`.

The trick is to generate `row_ind` and `col_ind` by iterating over the documents and creating a list of tuples (doc_id, word_id). `data` would simply be a vector of ones of the same length.

Multiplying the docs-words matrix by its transpose would give you the co-occurences matrix.

Additionally, this is efficient in terms of both run times and memory usage, so it should also handle big corpuses.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix


def create_co_occurences_matrix(allowed_words, documents):
    print(f"allowed_words:\n{allowed_words}")
    print(f"documents:\n{documents}")
    word_to_id = dict(zip(allowed_words, range(len(allowed_words))))
    documents_as_ids = [np.sort([word_to_id[w] for w in doc if w in word_to_id]).astype('uint32') for doc in documents]
    row_ind, col_ind = zip(*itertools.chain(*[[(i, w) for w in doc] for i, doc in enumerate(documents_as_ids)]))
    data = np.ones(len(row_ind), dtype='uint32')  # use unsigned int for better memory utilization
    max_word_id = max(itertools.chain(*documents_as_ids)) + 1
    docs_words_matrix = csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), shape=(len(documents_as_ids), max_word_id))  # efficient arithmetic operations with CSR * CSR
    words_cooc_matrix = docs_words_matrix.T * docs_words_matrix  # multiplying docs_words_matrix with its transpose matrix would generate the co-occurences matrix
    words_cooc_matrix.setdiag(0)
    print(f"words_cooc_matrix:\n{words_cooc_matrix.todense()}")
    return words_cooc_matrix, word_to_id
```

Run example:

```
allowed_words = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
documents = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'B', 'K'],['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Z']]
words_cooc_matrix, word_to_id = create_co_occurences_matrix(allowed_words, documents)
```

Output:

```
allowed_words:
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

documents:
[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'B', 'K'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Z']]

words_cooc_matrix:
[[0 2 1 1]
 [2 0 2 1]
 [1 2 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 15):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

document = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

occurrences = OrderedDict((name, OrderedDict((name, 0) for name in names)) for name in names)

# Find the co-occurrences:
for l in document:
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for item in l[:i] + l[i + 1:]:
            occurrences[l[i]][item] += 1

# Print the matrix:
print(' ', ' '.join(occurrences.keys()))
for name, values in occurrences.items():
    print(name, ' '.join(str(i) for i in values.values()))
```

Output;

```
  A B C D
A 0 2 1 1 
B 2 0 2 1 
C 1 2 0 1 
D 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use matrix tricks in order to find the co-occurrence matrix too. Hope this works well when you have bigger vocabulary.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
voc2id = dict(zip(names, range(len(names))))
rows, cols, vals = [], [], []
for r, d in enumerate(document):
    for e in d:
        if voc2id.get(e) is not None:
            rows.append(r)
            cols.append(voc2id[e])
            vals.append(1)
X = sp.csr_matrix((vals, (rows, cols)))
```

Now, you can find coocurrence matrix by simple multiply `X.T` with `X`

```
Xc = (X.T * X) # coocurrence matrix
Xc.setdiag(0)
print(Xc.toarray())
```

Comment: I tried your mentioned solution, but it adds new strings to the final matrix, though, I am only interested in strings inside the names list, not all of other strings in the document.

Comment: Best solution !!

Answer (score 8):

Here is another solution using `itertools` and the `Counter` class from the `collections` module.

```
import numpy
import itertools
from collections import Counter

document =[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'B'],['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

# Get all of the unique entries you have
varnames = tuple(sorted(set(itertools.chain(*document))))

# Get a list of all of the combinations you have
expanded = [tuple(itertools.combinations(d, 2)) for d in document]
expanded = itertools.chain(*expanded)

# Sort the combinations so that A,B and B,A are treated the same
expanded = [tuple(sorted(d)) for d in expanded]

# count the combinations
c = Counter(expanded)


# Create the table
table = numpy.zeros((len(varnames),len(varnames)), dtype=int)

for i, v1 in enumerate(varnames):
    for j, v2 in enumerate(varnames[i:]):        
        j = j + i 
        table[i, j] = c[v1, v2]
        table[j, i] = c[v1, v2]

# Display the output
for row in table:
    print(row)
```

The output (which could be easilty turned into a DataFrame) is:

```
[0 2 1 1]
[2 0 2 1]
[1 2 0 1]
[1 1 1 0]
```

Answer (score 6):

We can hugely simplify this using `NetworkX`. Here`names` are the nodes we want to consider, and the lists in `document` contains nodes to connect.

We can connect the nodes in each sublist taking the length 2 `combinations`, and create a `MultiGraph` to account for the co-occurrence:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

G = nx.from_edgelist((c for n_nodes in document for c in combinations(n_nodes, r=2)),
                     create_using=nx.MultiGraph)
nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G, nodelist=names, dtype='int')

   A  B  C  D
A  0  2  1  1
B  2  0  2  1
C  1  2  0  1
D  1  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue... So i came with this code. This code takes into account context window and then determines co_occurance matrix.

Hope this helps you...

```
def countOccurences(word,context_window): 

    """
    This function returns the count of context word.
    """ 
    return context_window.count(word)

def co_occurance(feature_dict,corpus,window = 5):
    """
    This function returns co_occurance matrix for the given window size. Default is 5.

    """
    length = len(feature_dict)
    co_matrix = np.zeros([length,length]) # n is the count of all words

    corpus_len = len(corpus)
    for focus_word in top_features:

        for context_word in top_features[top_features.index(focus_word):]:
            # print(feature_dict[context_word])
            if focus_word == context_word:
                co_matrix[feature_dict[focus_word],feature_dict[context_word]] = 0
            else:
                start_index = 0
                count = 0
                while(focus_word in corpus[start_index:]):

                    # get the index of focus word
                    start_index = corpus.index(focus_word,start_index)
                    fi,li = max(0,start_index - window) , min(corpus_len-1,start_index + window)

                    count += countOccurences(context_word,corpus[fi:li+1])
                    # updating start index
                    start_index += 1

                # update [Aij]
                co_matrix[feature_dict[focus_word],feature_dict[context_word]] = count
                # update [Aji]
                co_matrix[feature_dict[context_word],feature_dict[focus_word]] = count
    return co_matrix
```

Answer (score -1):

'''for a window of 2, data_corpus is the series consisting of text data, words is the list consisting of words for which co-occurence matrix is build'''

"co_oc is the co-occurence matrix"

```
co_oc=pd.DataFrame(index=words,columns=words)

for j in tqdm(data_corpus):

    k=j.split()

    for l in range(len(k)):

        if l>=5 and l<(len(k)-6):
            if k[l] in words:
                for m in range(l-5,l+6):
                    if m==l:
                        continue
                    elif k[m] in words:
                        co_oc[k[l]][k[m]]+=1

        elif l>=(len(k)-6):
            if k[l] in words:
                for m in range(l-5,len(k)):
                    if m==l:
                        continue
                    elif k[m] in words:
                        co_oc[k[l]][k[m]]+=1

        else:
            if k[l] in words:
                for m in range(0,l+5):
                    if m==l:
                        continue
                    elif k[m] in words:
                        co_oc[k[l]][k[m]]+=1
print(co_oc.head())
```