# Python. Count co-occurrences in columns values of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 4, 7, 5, 6], 'c2': [2, 5, 1, 7, 8], 'c3': [3, 1, 2, 4, 6], 'c4': [3, 9, 5, 4, 8], 'c5': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'c6': [2, 5, 1, 7, 8]})
```

Digits represent a code of product (they are not numbers). I'm looking for something like correlation matrix, to compare similarity of columns (count intersections). Could you please help writing a loop counting number of similar codes for all columns?

**Sample output:**

```
C1 with c2 ... times, c3... times, c4... times, c5... times, c6... times
C2 with c3... times, c4... times, c5... times, c6... times
C3 with c4... times, c5... times, c6... times    
And so on
```

P.S. I checked for duplicates, but was not able to find same problem.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Either mentioned above, or, ideally, as correlation matrix with values.
Where value = number of intersections.

Comment: Something like `df.T.dot(df)`

Comment: @pygo - no, because OP need `Digits represent a code of product (they are not numbers)`

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814452/co-occurrence-matrix-from-list-of-words-in-python/42814963)  or  [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @jezrael,  you are good to turn on a answer then for sure :-)

Comment: @pygo - no experience with this typo of problems, but seems Rafael add answer in dupe answer.

Comment: I got the same thread which i mentioned above :-)