# How can I convert a two column array to a matrix with counts of occurences?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I have the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

pair_array = np.array([(205, 254), (205, 382), (254, 382), (18, 69), (205, 382), 
                       (31, 183), (31, 267), (31, 382), (183, 267), (183, 382)])

print(pair_array)

#[[205 254]
# [205 382]
# [254 382]
# [ 18  69]
# [205 382]
# [ 31 183]
# [ 31 267]
# [ 31 382]
# [183 267]
# [183 382]]
```

Is there a way to transform this array to a symmetric pandas Dataframe that contains the count of occurences for all possible combinations?
I expect something along the lines of this:

```
#     18  31  69 183 205 254 267 382 
#  18  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
#  31  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1
#  69  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 183  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
# 205  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
# 254  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
# 267  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 382  0   1   0   1   2   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way could be to build a graph using [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) and obtain the adjacency matrix directly as a dataframe with [`nx.to_pandas_adjacency`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_adjacency.html). To account for the co-occurrences of the *edges* in the graph, we can create a [`nx.MultiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html?highlight=multigraph#networkx.MultiGraph), which allows for multiple edges connecting the same pair of nodes:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist(pair_array, create_using=nx.MultiGraph)
nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G, nodelist=sorted(G.nodes()), dtype='int')

      18   31   69   183  205  254  267  382
18     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
31     0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1
69     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
183    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1
205    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    2
254    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
267    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
382    0    1    0    1    2    1    0    0
```

Building a `NetworkX` graph, will also enable to create an adjacency matrix or another depending on the behaviour we expect. We can either create it using a:

- `nx.Graph`: If we want to set to `1` both entries `(x,y)` and (`y,x`) for a `(x,y)` (or `(y,x)`) edge. This will hence produce a symmetric adjacency matrix
- `nx.DiGraph`: If `(x,y)` should only set the `(x,y)` the entry to `1`
- `nx.MultiGraph`: For the same behaviour as a `nx.Graph` but accounting for edge co-occurrences
- `nx.MultiDiGraph`: For the same behaviour as a `nx.DiGraph` but also accounting for edge co-occurrences

Answer (score 8):

One way of doing it is appending the `pair_array` with `pair_array` reversed at axis 1 which can be done using `[::-1]`. And to append use [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)/[`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)/[`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Now use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to perform cross tabulation.

```
all_vals = np.r_[pair_array, pair_array[:, ::-1]]
pd.crosstab(all_vals[:, 0], all_vals[:, 1])

col_0  18   31   69   183  205  254  267  382
row_0                                        
18       0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
31       0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1
69       1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
183      0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1
205      0    0    0    0    0    1    0    2
254      0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
267      0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
382      0    1    0    1    2    1    0    0
```

As [@QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) pointed when there are identical pairs occurring more than one time i.e `[(18, 18), (18, 18), ...]`, then use

```
rev = pair_array[:, ::-1]
m = (pair_array == rev)
rev = rev[~np.all(m, axis=1)]
all_vals = np.r_[pair_arr, rev]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a data frame of the appropriate size with zeros beforehand and just increment the appropriate cells by looping over the pairs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pair_array = np.array([(205, 254), (205, 382), (254, 382), (18, 69), (205, 382),
                       (31, 183), (31, 267), (31, 82), (183, 267), (183, 382)])

vals = sorted(set(pair_array.flatten()))
n = len(vals)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int), columns=vals, index=vals)

for r, c in pair_array:
    df.at[r, c] += 1
    df.at[c, r] += 1

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     18   31   69   82   183  205  254  267  382
18     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
31     0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0
69     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
82     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
183    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
205    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    2
254    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
267    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
382    0    0    0    0    1    2    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(pair_array[:,0], pair_array[:,1])
```

Output:

```
col_0  69   82   183  254  267  382
row_0                              
18       1    0    0    0    0    0
31       0    1    1    0    1    0
183      0    0    0    0    1    1
205      0    0    0    1    0    2
254      0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match OPs expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay to add pandas as a dependency you can use this implementation

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(pair_array)
>>> pd.crosstab(df[0], df[1])
1    69   183  254  267  382
0
18     1    0    0    0    0
31     0    1    0    1    1
183    0    0    0    1    1
205    0    0    1    0    2
254    0    0    0    0    1
```