# Find the number of co occurrence in a matrix of dafa frame in r programming

Tags: r

I have got data frame with the rows (5000000) as customers and rows(500) as products.

```
Cust/Pro  P1  P2   P3  P4
C1        1     0  0   1
C2        0     1  0   1
C3        1     1  0   0
C4        1     0  1   1
```

I want to convert this into

```
   P1  P2 P3  P4
P1 3   0  1   2
P2 0   2  0   1
P3 1   0  1   1
P4 2   1  1   3
```

It also needs to be efficient since the data frame size is also big. Tried correlation and cos product of matrix. No getting the exact result.

Comment: Care to explain the logic behind the transformation?

Comment: This is a crossproduct: `crossprod(as.matrix(dat[-1]))` and a duplicate question (if better explained of course).

Comment: This format is best for comparing it with other data frames of similar nature and understanding.

Comment: The answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix might be helpful