# Forming a co-occurence matrix from a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame which looks something like this:

```
id  val
1    a
1    b
2    a
2    c
2    d
3    a
3    a
```

think of each row as a label, val, that was given to some observation with an id.

What I ultimately want to get to is a "co-occurence" matrix that looks something like this where I get a count of how many times each letter appears within the same id with each other letter:

```
    a  b  c  d
a   1  1  1  1
b   1  0  0  0
c   1  0  0  1
d   1  0  1  0
```

I've been wracking my brain looking for ways to do this, but have come up empty so far. Any hints? Preferably using tidyverse tools, but open to other options as well at this point.

EDIT: the solutions to the question linked as a possible duplicate do not work in this case. I'm not sure why, but I suspect it has to do with that question having a data frame with 3 columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating co-occurrence matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix)

Comment: That question is 5 years old, so I hope that there is a more straightforward solution now. I tried 2 or 3 of the solutions there and none of them work, so my question is different (maybe because it lacks a third column?)

Comment: I've just noticed that my original solution is very similar to @d.b's, so I have changed it to add some value.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the best answer if it solves your problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in base R. Not quite elegant but seems to work

```
temp = data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(a)
    combn(a$val, 2))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sapply(sort(unique(df$val)), function(rows)
    sapply(sort(unique(df$val)), function(cols)
        sum(sapply(temp, function(x)
            identical(sort(x), sort(c(rows, cols)))))))
#  a b c d
#a 1 1 1 1
#b 1 0 0 0
#c 1 0 0 1
#d 1 0 1 0
```

OR with `igraph`

```
temp = t(do.call(cbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(a) combn(a$val, 2))))
library(igraph)
as.matrix(get.adjacency(graph(temp, directed = FALSE)))
#  a c b d
#a 1 1 1 1
#c 1 0 0 1
#b 1 0 0 0
#d 1 1 0 0
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
                    val = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "a", "a")),
               .Names = c("id", "val"),
               class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr` + `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  split(.$id) %>%
  map_dfr(function(x){
    t(combn(x$val, 2)) %>% 
      data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(factor(., levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d")))) %>%
  table() %>%
  pmax(., t(.))
```

**Result:**

```
   X2
X1  a b c d
  a 1 1 1 1
  b 1 0 0 0
  c 1 0 0 1
  d 1 0 1 0
```

**Notes:**

1. I first split the `df` by `id`, then used `map_dfr` from `purrr` to map the `combn` function to each id group.
2. `combn` finds all combinations of elements within a vector (length(vec) choose 2) and returns a matrix.
3. `_dfr` at the end of `map_dfr` means that the result will be a dataframe by row binding each element of the list. So this is effectively `do.call(rbind, lapply())`.
4. `mutate_all` makes sures that `table` retains all the levels needed even if a letter does not exist in a column.
5. Finally, since after the `table` step, an upper triangular matrix is produced, I fed that matrix and its transpose into `pmax`
6. `pmax` finds the parallel maxima from the two inputs and returns a symmetric matrix as desired.

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text=  "id  val
                1    a
                1    b
                2    a
                2    c
                2    d
                3    a
                3    a", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```