# counts of combinations of values in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have a dataframe like so:

```
    df<-structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", 
"D", "E", "E"), expertise = c("r", "python", "julia", "python", 
"r", "python", "julia", "python", "julia", "r", "julia")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), .Names = c("id", 
"expertise"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), expertise = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("id", "expertise")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))

df
   id expertise
1   A         r
2   A    python
3   A     julia
4   B    python
5   B         r
6   C    python
7   C     julia
8   D    python
9   D     julia
10  E         r
11  E     julia
```

I can get the overall counts of "expertise" by using:

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>% group_by(expertise) %>% mutate (counts_overall= n())
```

However what I want is the counts for combinations of expertise values. In other words how many "id" had the same combination of two expertise e.g. "r" and"julia"?
Here is a desired output:

```
df_out<-structure(list(expertise1 = c("r", "r", "python"), expertise2 = c("python", 
"julia", "julia"), count = c(2L, 2L, 3L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("expertise1", 
"expertise2", "count"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    expertise1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), expertise2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), count = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("expertise1", "expertise2", "count"
)), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))

df_out
  expertise1 expertise2 count
1          r     python     2
2          r      julia     2
3     python      julia     3
```

Comment: The off-diagonals of `crossprod(table(df)>0)` should do it I think.

Comment: @thelatemail post as an answer ?

Comment: @RonakShah - looking for a duplicate because I know I stole that from someone smarter than me!

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix?noredirect

Comment: Just to get the same desired output format, we can expand @thelatemail answer: 

    `df_out <- crossprod(table(df)>0) %>% melt();`

    `colnames(df_out) <- c("exp1", "exp2", "count") ;`  

    `df_out %>% filter(exp1 != exp2, count > 0) %>% arrange(desc(count));`

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail. This works great and should have used cooccurence matrix when  doing the search for duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660945/3817004) from [latemail's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923115/counts-of-combinations-of-values-in-a-dataframe-r#comment90796269_51923115) creates a matrix

```
crossprod(table(df) > 0)
```

> ```
>          expertise
> expertise julia python r
>    julia      4      3 2
>    python     3      4 2
>    r          2      2 3
> ```

while the OP expects a dataframe in long format.

#### 1) cross join

Below is a `data.table` solution which uses the `CJ()` (*cross join*) function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, CJ(expertise, expertise)[V1 < V2], by = id][
  , .N, by = .(expertise1 = V1, expertise2 = V2)]
```

> ```
>    expertise1 expertise2 N
> 1:      julia     python 3
> 2:      julia          r 2
> 3:     python          r 2
> ```

`CJ(expertise, expertise)[V1 < V2]` is the `data.table` equivalent for `t(combn(df$expertise, 2))` or `combinat::combn2(df$expertise)`.

#### 2) self-join

Here is another variant which uses a *self-join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df, on = "id", allow = TRUE][
  expertise < i.expertise, .N, by = .(expertise1 = expertise, expertise2 = i.expertise)]
```

> ```
>    expertise1 expertise2 N
> 1:     python          r 2
> 2:      julia          r 2
> 3:      julia     python 3
> ```

Answer (score 2):

A solution not as efficient as crossprod-table approach but easy to understand:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(expertise = list(combn(sort(expertise), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = '_'))) %>%
    unnest(expertise) %>%
    group_by(expertise) %>%
    summarize(count = n()) %>%
    separate(expertise, c('expertise1', 'expertise2'), sep = '_')

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   expertise1 expertise2 count
#   <chr>      <chr>      <int>
# 1 julia      python         3
# 2 julia      r              2
# 3 python     r              2
```