# R - A loop comparing elements in common between two hierarchical lists

Tags: r, list, loops, sapply

I have been trying, for some time, to build a matrix populated by the counts of elements in common between two herarchical lists.

Here is some dummy data:

```
site<-c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B')
group<-c('A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A3','A3', 
'B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2')
element<-c("red","orange","blue","black","white", "black","cream","yellow","purple","red","orange","blue","white","gray","salmon")
d<-cbind(site,group,element)
```

I created a list structure, assuming it would be procedural due to the different number os elements in each list. Also, since I don´t want every possible comparison between groups, but only between sites.

```
#first level list - by site
sitelist<-split(nodmod, list(nodmod$site),drop = TRUE)
#list by group 
nestedlist <- lapply(sitelist, function(x) split(x, x[['mod']], drop = TRUE))
```

My intention is to create a table, or matrix with the number of element in common between groups from the two sites (my original data has additional sites). Like such:

```
    A1  A2  A3
B1  2   0   0
B2  0   2   0
```

The nested nature of this problem is challenging to me. I am not as familiar with lists, as I´ve solved problems mostly using dataframes. My attempt boiled down to this. I felt it got close, but have many shortcomings with the correct syntax for loops.

```
t <- outer(1:length(d$A),
         1:length(d$B),
         FUN=function(i,j){
           sapply(1:length(i),
                  FUN=function(x) 
                    length(intersect(d$A[[i]]$element, d$B[[j]]$element)) )
         })
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Apologies if a similar problem has been solved. I have scoured the internet, but have not found it, or did not comprehend the solution to make it transferable to mine.

Comment: Row 10 has `site = A` and `group = B1`. Is that correct?

Comment: my mistake, editing right now.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a co-occurrence matrix. You can start from a data.frame structure, using `data.frame()` instead of `cbind()`, and then `crossprod(table(d[,c(3,2)]))`. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar approach to @Parfait's using matrix multiplication. You may need to play around with the data generation to extend it to your application:

```
site<-c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B')
group<-c('A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A3','A3', 
         'B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2')
element<-c("red","orange","blue","black","white", "black","cream","yellow","purple","red","orange","blue","white","gray","salmon")

d<-data.frame(group, el = as.factor(element), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


As <- d[group %in% paste0("A", 1:3), ]
Bs <- d[group %in% paste0("B", 1:2), ]

A_mat <- as.matrix(table(As))
B_mat <- as.matrix(table(Bs))
```

Results:

```
> A_mat
         el
group black blue cream gray orange purple red salmon white yellow
   A1     0    0     0    0      1      0   1      0     0      0
   A2     1    1     0    0      0      0   0      0     1      0
   A3     1    0     1    0      0      1   0      0     0      1


> B_mat
         el
group black blue cream gray orange purple red salmon white yellow
   B1     0    0     0    0      1      0   1      0     0      0
   B2     0    1     0    1      0      0   0      1     1      0


> B_mat %*% t(A_mat)
     group
group A1 A2 A3
   B1  2  0  0
   B2  0  2  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider matrix multiplication `x %*% y` (see `?matmult`) by creating a helper matrix of unique *element* values by unique *group* values assigning ones in each corresponding cell. Then run the matrix multiplication as the transpose with itself, followed by subset of rows and columns:

```
# EMPTY MATRIX
helper_mat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(unique(element)), ncol=length(unique(group)),
                     dimnames=list(unique(element), unique(group)))

# ASSIGN 1's AT SELECT LOCATIONS
for(i in seq_along(site)) {
  helper_mat[element[i], group[i]] <- 1
}

helper_mat
#        A1 A2 A3 B1 B2
# red     1  0  0  1  0
# orange  1  0  0  1  0
# blue    0  1  0  0  1
# black   0  1  1  0  0
# white   0  1  0  0  1
# cream   0  0  1  0  0
# yellow  0  0  1  0  0
# purple  0  0  1  0  0
# gray    0  0  0  0  1
# salmon  0  0  0  0  1

# MATRIX MULTIPLICATION WITH SUBSET
final_mat <- t(helper_mat) %*% helper_mat
final_mat <- final_mat[grep("B", rownames(final_mat)), grep("A", colnames(final_mat))]

final_mat
#    A1 A2 A3
# B1  2  0  0
# B2  0  2  0
```

---

Even shorter version thanks to @Lamia:

```
helper_mat <- table(element, group)

final_mat <- t(helper_mat) %*% helper_mat # ALTERNATIVELY: crossprod(helper_mat)

final_mat <- final_mat[grep("B", rownames(final_mat)), grep("A", colnames(final_mat))]

final_mat
#      group
# group A1 A2 A3
#    B1  2  0  0
#    B2  0  2  0
```

Comment: This can be simplified using `crossprod(table(d$element,d$group))`

Comment: Absolutely @Lamia, `table` was what I needed for uniqueness and `crossprod` variant of matmult.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. How is it possible to tweak this code to create an output as a list of elements in each intersection? For example, the colors contained in B1/A1 and B2/A2?

Comment: That request warrants a new question as you are substantially changing desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
# example dataset
site<-c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B')
group<-c('A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A3','A3', 
         'B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2')
element<-c("red","orange","blue","black","white", "black","cream","yellow","purple","red","orange","blue","white","gray","salmon")
d<-cbind(site,group,element)

library(tidyverse)

# save as dataframe
d = data.frame(d)

expand.grid(groupA = unique(d$group[d$site=="A"]),
            groupB = unique(d$group[d$site=="B"])) %>%               # get all combinations of A and B columns
  rowwise() %>%                                                      # for each row
  mutate(counts = length(intersect(d$element[d$group==groupA], 
                                   d$element[d$group==groupB]))) %>% # count common elements
  spread(groupA, counts) %>%                                         # reshape data
  data.frame() %>%                                                   
  column_to_rownames("groupB")

#    A1 A2 A3
# B1  2  0  0
# B2  0  2  0
```

Instead of `rowwise` you can use a vectorised function that will be (automatically) applied to each row, like this:

```
# create a function and vectorise it
CountCommonElements = function(x, y) length(intersect(d$element[d$group==x], d$element[d$group==y]))
CountCommonElements = Vectorize(CountCommonElements)

expand.grid(groupA = unique(d$group[d$site=="A"]),
            groupB = unique(d$group[d$site=="B"])) %>%                                                              
  mutate(counts = CountCommonElements(groupA, groupB)) %>% 
  spread(groupA, counts) %>%                                       
  data.frame() %>%                                                   
  column_to_rownames("groupB")

#    A1 A2 A3
# B1  2  0  0
# B2  0  2  0
```

Comment: unfortunately, there were some issues with this package: 'Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.'     It seems to be linked to the mutate function and the solutions proposed to this problem go beyond my R skills.

Comment: Could be the package, or the R version that you're using. Do you know if they are the latest versions?

Comment: It is R-3.4.0. It seems to be a problem associated to Windows versions. Updating right now, but I´ve read of people trying to downgrade.

Comment: I´ve installed the latest version and it´s working fine. Thank you!

Comment: btw, I am still curious as to how this problem could be tackled with base R, but for what I need at the moment, this wil definitely do!