# Transform relationship pairs into a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse, data-transfer

I have one data frame like this. The `id` of each line is unique and the `type` defines the group of the `id`.

```
id  type
a   a1
b   a1
c   a2
d   a3
e   a4
f   a4
```

I want to make a matrix like below. The value would be 1 if the two `id` belong to the same `type`, otherwise 0.

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f
a   1   1   0   0   0   0
b   1   1   0   0   0   0
c   0   0   1   0   0   0
d   0   0   0   1   0   0
e   0   0   0   0   1   1
f   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

The data frame is large (over 70 thousands line), and I do not know how to do this efficiently in R. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: creating a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, and I think you can use the following code

```
M <- crossprod(t(table(df)))
```

or

```
M <- crossprod(table(rev(df)))
```

such that

```
> M
   id
id  a b c d e f
  a 1 1 0 0 0 0
  b 1 1 0 0 0 0
  c 0 0 1 0 0 0
  d 0 0 0 1 0 0
  e 0 0 0 0 1 1
  f 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), type = c("a1", 
"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. It is very useful. But I get another question: since the data frame I have is very large (over 10 thousands lines), I found the way above quite slow. Is there any way to speed up? Please ignore me if it is unrealistic.

Comment: @niuyw I think this might already be a very efficient approach, according to my knowledge...