# Co-occurance matrix in R, summing values of a variable to fill in cells

Tags: r, matrix, sum, tidyverse

I have a long dataframe in R right now.  I am working from another similar post ([Creating co-occurrence matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix)).  The example dataset is this:

```
#read in your data
dat <- read.table(text="TrxID Items Quant
Trx1 A 3
Trx1 B 1
Trx1 C 1
Trx2 E 3
Trx2 B 1
Trx3 B 1
Trx3 C 4
Trx4 D 1
Trx4 E 1
Trx4 A 1
Trx5 F 5
Trx5 B 3
Trx5 C 2
Trx5 D 1", header=T)
```

They counted the number of co-occurances and built a final matrix that looked like this:

```
   A B C D E F
A  2 1 1 0 1 1
B  1 4 3 1 1 0
C  1 3 3 1 0 0
D  1 1 1 2 1 1
E  1 1 0 1 2 0
F  0 1 1 1 0 1
```

using this code:

```
crossprod(table(dat[1:2]))
```

Note - in the previous example they wanted the diagonal to be 0, but I do not here, so I have changed the example so the diagonal is not set to 0 here.

I want to do essentially the same thing as above, but **instead of filling the cells of the matrix with the co-occurrence counts, I want the values to be the sum of the variable `Quant` across co-occurring records**.  In this case, the final matrix should look like:

```
   A B  C  D E F
A  4 4  4  2 2 0
B  4 6  12 4 4 8
C  4 12 7  3 0 7
D  2 4  3  2 2 6
E  2 4  0  2 4 0
F  0 8  7  6 0 5
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions.  I generally use tidyverse personally.

Comment: how do you get A-B to be 4 for example?

Comment: Because A and B only co-occur in/share one treatment - Trx1, where A has a Quant value of 3 and B has a Quant value of 1, so 1+3 = 4.  

B-C is 12 because the co-occurrences are Trx1, Trx13, and Trx5, so adding up the Quant values for these records gives 1+1+3+1+4+2 = 12.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
e <- crossprod(s<-xtabs(Quant~., dat), s>0)
e + t(e) - diag(diag(e))

   Items
Items A  B  C D E F
    A 4  4  4 2 2 0
    B 4  6 12 4 4 8
    C 4 12  7 3 0 7
    D 2  4  3 2 2 6
    E 2  4  0 2 4 0
    F 0  8  7 6 0 5
```

Note that `diag(e)` is the same as `xtabs(Quant~Items, dat)`

Comment: @rt11 No. you should probably break it down into two lines of code `s<-xtabs(Quant~., dat); e <- crossprod(s, s>0)`