# How to turn two column dataframe into a word cooccurrence matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, nlp, data-wrangling

I have a R dataframe that consists of two columns, `id` and `text`, and I want to turn it into a cooccurrence matrix of word pairs that appear together in the same `id`'s list of words.
So, this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), text = c(but, the, and, but, a, the))
```

should be turned into something like this:

|  | but | the | and | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| but | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| the | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| and | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| a | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

But at larger scale. I think this toy example should be transferable though. I'm not sure where to even start here, but tidyverse solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix) answer:

```
dat <- crossprod(table(df))
```