# loop combination two columns Sums in R

Tags: r, for-loop, combinations, purrr

I try to make a column combination by sum in R. It needs to analyse for association order in warehouse.

For example

Raw_table

```
Order |  SKU  | QTY
\#1    | Banana | 1
\#1    | Apple  | 2
\#1    | Pear   | 1
\#1    | Cherry | 2
\#2    | Banana | 4
\#2    | Apple  | 1
\#2    | Grape  | 1
\#3    | Banana | 2
\#3    | Pear   | 1
```

Transform table by outbound frequency

```
Order | Banana | Apple | Pear | Cherry | Grape
\#1    |   1    |   1   |  1   |  1     |
\#2    |   1    |   1   |      |        |  1
\#3    |   1    |       |  1   |        |
```

make a pair to highest SKU

```
SKU1   | SKU2  | Free
Banana | Apple | 2
Banana | Pear  | 2
Banana | Cherry| 1
Banana | Grape | 1
Apple  | pear  | 1
Apple  |Cherry | 1
Apple  |Grape  | 1
Pear   |Cherry | 1
```

Banana pair needs to concentrate to batch or located in warehouse.

I'm a beginner in loop , try to map in purrr, for text, pairwise anything else. i can not find information

i want to know how to solve this pair

I'm used to treat over 10,000 SKU usually

Purrr , pairwise, whatever method i don't mind , i want to solve this matrix

Comment: I'm trying to understand the result you are going for. Table2: Why is the value for Apple for Order #1 1 when, when the raw table shows 2 banans for order 1. Is the third table supposed to show how many times two items are part of the same order? If yes, why is Banana|Grape 0? Order #2 combines banana and grape.

Comment: The core of this I believe is a crossproduct to create a co-occurrence matrix - e.g.: `crossprod(table(dat$Order, dat$SKU))` as seen at this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix You can convert that result to a long data.frame if you prefer that output.

Comment: @Till Question 1 is I just need to check frequecy in Order , so table 2's #1 apple is 1. question 2 is I 've amended cherry, frequency

Comment: @thelatemail your link is really good for co-occurrence matrix I'm try!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `crossprod` + `xtabs` + `as.data.frame.table`

```
> tbl <- crossprod(!!xtabs(QTY ~ ., df))

> tbl[upper.tri(tbl, TRUE)] <- NA

> na.omit(as.data.frame.table(tbl))
        SKU    SKU.1 Freq
2   Banana   Apple      2
3   Cherry   Apple      1
4   Grape    Apple      1
5   Pear     Apple      1
8   Cherry   Banana     1
9   Grape    Banana     1
10  Pear     Banana     2
14  Grape    Cherry     0
15  Pear     Cherry     1
20  Pear     Grape      0
```

or if you want to remove the `0` cooccurrences, you can try

```
> tbl <- crossprod(!!xtabs(QTY ~ ., df))

> tbl[upper.tri(tbl, TRUE) | tbl < 1] <- NA

> na.omit(as.data.frame.table(tbl))
        SKU    SKU.1 Freq
2   Banana   Apple      2
3   Cherry   Apple      1
4   Grape    Apple      1
5   Pear     Apple      1
8   Cherry   Banana     1
9   Grape    Banana     1
10  Pear     Banana     2
15  Pear     Cherry     1
```

## Data

```
df <- structure(list(Order = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), SKU = c(" Banana ",
" Apple  ", " Pear   ", " Cherry ", " Banana ", " Apple  ", " Grape  ", 
" Banana ", " Pear   "), QTY = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried then, finally succeed.