# How do I count the number of times each item co-occurs with every other item in a list?

Tags: r, count

There're a lot of questions in this general space with excellent solutions, but I'm having a hard time applying them to my data. I have long-form data where one column gives us the observation and the other gives us the members in the observation. All I want to do is count how many times every member co-occurs with each other member.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(salad = c(rep("Green", 4), rep("Caprese", 3), rep("Fruit", 3)),
                 ingredients = c("Lettuce", "Tomato", "Onion", "Olives",
                                 "Tomato", "Onion", "Mozzarella",
                                 "Melon", "Orange", "Tomato"))

df

     salad ingredients
1    Green     Lettuce
2    Green      Tomato
3    Green       Onion
4    Green      Olives
5  Caprese      Tomato
6  Caprese       Onion
7  Caprese  Mozzarella
8    Fruit       Melon
9    Fruit      Orange
10   Fruit      Tomato
```

What I want to do is produce a table with every possible combination of members (ingredients) and count how many times they co-occur in an observation (salad). It'd look something like this:

```
results

    ingredient_A     ingredient_B      count
1   Lettuce          Tomato            1
2   Lettuce          Onion             1
3   Lettuce          Olives            1
4   Lettuce          Mozzarella    0
5   Lettuce          Melon             0
6   Lettuce          Orange            0
7   Tomato           Onion             2
8   Tomato           Olives            1
9   Tomato           Mozzarella    1
10  Tomato           Melon             1
…   …            …             …
```

I feel like the answer is going to be really simple, but I'm having a difficult time right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is again a co-occurrence table essentially, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281303/creating-co-occurrence-matrix - so `cp <- crossprod(table(df)); as.data.frame.table(cp)[lower.tri(cp),]`

Answer (score 8):

Here's a dplyr/tidyr approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  left_join(., ., by = join_by(salad, ingredients < ingredients), suffix = c("_A", "_B")) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  count(ingredients_A, ingredients_B, name = "count")
#    ingredients_A ingredients_B count
# 1        Lettuce        Olives     1
# 2        Lettuce         Onion     1
# 3        Lettuce        Tomato     1
# 4          Melon        Orange     1
# 5          Melon        Tomato     1
# 6     Mozzarella         Onion     1
# 7     Mozzarella        Tomato     1
# 8         Olives         Onion     1
# 9         Olives        Tomato     1
# 10         Onion        Tomato     2
# 11        Orange        Tomato     1
```

The `left_join(., ., ...)` is a self-join, using two `.`'s just for intent and clarity. The `ingredients < ingredients` allows us to be confident that we don't have self-joins (`Tomato, Tomato`) and both sides of a pairing (`Tomato, Lettuce` and `Lettuce, Tomato`) within each `salad`.

Perhaps a bit busier, a base R variant could be:

```r
split(df, df$salad) |>
  lapply(function(z) merge(z, z, by = "salad", suffix = c("_A", "_B")) |>
  subset(ingredients_A < ingredients_B)) |>
  do.call(what = rbind.data.frame) |>
  xtabs(~ ingredients_A + ingredients_B, data = _) |>
  as.data.frame.table(responseName = "count") |>
  subset(count > 0)
#    ingredients_A ingredients_B count
# 1        Lettuce        Olives     1
# 7        Lettuce         Onion     1
# 9     Mozzarella         Onion     1
# 10        Olives         Onion     1
# 14         Melon        Orange     1
# 19       Lettuce        Tomato     1
# 20         Melon        Tomato     1
# 21    Mozzarella        Tomato     1
# 22        Olives        Tomato     1
# 23         Onion        Tomato     2
# 24        Orange        Tomato     1
```

The base-R variant does a full cartesian join (within each salad), which means that if the number of ingredients-per-salad in your real data is rather large, this might get expensive.

And for good measure, because no deed needs to be just two dialects ;-)

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, int := match(ingredients, sort(unique(ingredients)))
  ][DT, on = .(salad, int < int)
  ][!is.na(ingredients), .(count = .N), by = .(ingredients, i.ingredients)]
#     ingredients i.ingredients count
#          <char>        <char> <int>
#  1:     Lettuce        Tomato     1
#  2:       Onion        Tomato     2
#  3:      Olives        Tomato     1
#  4:     Lettuce         Onion     1
#  5:      Olives         Onion     1
#  6:     Lettuce        Olives     1
#  7:  Mozzarella        Tomato     1
#  8:  Mozzarella         Onion     1
#  9:       Melon        Orange     1
# 10:       Melon        Tomato     1
# 11:      Orange        Tomato     1
```

I add `int` since `data.table` supports inequility joins but not on strings; therefore, `int < int` is analogous to dplyr's `ingredients < ingredients`.

The only reason I included `sort(.)` in the calculation of `int` is so that the output would more-closely resemble the other two dialects; while the results would have effectively been the same, `Onion, Tomato` could instead be `Tomato, Onion`. Over to you if that is important.

Comment: this "self join" is awesome, never thought of it before

Comment: @GuedesBF it can get expensive, I'm hoping the real data doesn't explode ...

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. It works perfectly. I'm going to try to carefully look at how the self-join works because it's just so simple. Really appreciate it.