# Create an adjacency matrix from a csv file of three variables

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

So I have a csv file with three variables 'Team 1' 'Team 2' and 'Winner.'
I want to create an adjacency matrix that has rownames=colnames. Is there any way to get this done? This is what I want:

```
   A B C
A  0 2 1    
B  1 0 3    
C  2 4 0
```

So this particular matrix would indicate that A won from B 1 time and B from A 2 times and so on. The rownames indicate the winners.

For example, if my data looks like this:

```
   Team A       Team B      Winner
  Germany    Argentina     Germany
  Croatia      Germany     Croatia
Argentina      Croatia   Argentina
```

would give the matrix

```
            Germany Argentina   Croatia 
Germany           0         0         1  
Argentina         1         0         0  
Croatia           0         1         0
```

My code

```
data = as.matrix(read.csv("data.csv"))

labels = unique(c(data[,1],data[,2]))
A = matrix(0, length(labels),length(labels))

rownames(A) = colnames(A) <- labels
A
```

This creates the adjacency matrix, but how do I fill it in?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: what does that mean exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: not really tested but is `table(d[c(1,3)]) + table(d[c(2,3)])` enough? (where `d` is your dataframe) edit: and will want to set the diagonal to zero; `diag(result) <- 0`

Comment: It does not work

Comment: quite possibly, but more details please -- it works for your example

Comment: Okay so it does work! The diagonal thing was confusing me. Thank you!!

Comment: The problem now is that the rownames (result) are not equal to the colnames (result). Is there any way to address that?

Comment: Five, please see edit in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `table` to pull out the results.

First, you may want to set common levels for all teams

```
lvs <- sort(as.character(unique(unlist(d))))
d[] <- lapply(d, factor, levels=lvs)
```

Then `table` the data

```
res <- table(d[c("Team.A", "Winner")]) + table(d[c("Team.B", "Winner")])    
diag(res) <- 0
res

#            Winner
# Team.A      Argentina Croatia Germany
#   Argentina         0       0       1
#   Croatia           1       0       0
#   Germany           0       1       0
```

If you want a specific order, you could set the variables to factor before using `table`, or you can change the order after

```
vars <- c("Germany", "Argentina","Croatia")
res[vars, vars]
```

Data

```
d <- read.table(header=T, text="'Team A'       'Team B'      Winner
  Germany    Argentina     Germany
  Croatia      Germany     Croatia
Argentina      Croatia   Argentina")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? It creates a matrix with the teams like in your first example.

```
x = cbind(c(0, 1, 2), c(2, 0, 4), c(1, 3, 0))

colnames(x) <- c("Germany","Argentina","Croatia")
rownames(x) <- c("Germany","Argentina","Croatia")

x
```

Comment: Basically I have a huge data set with just the Team names and the winners of matches. I want to convert that to an adjacency matrix. This was just a simplified example.

Comment: There are three columns in this dataset: Team 1, Team 2 and Winner.

Comment: Are you after something like is shown here? http://rforjournalists.com/2016/09/24/creating-premier-league-results-matrix-in-r/

Comment: Yes something like this, but there are no scores included. I just want to show the number of matches won. Like in the example above

Comment: There are some examples here that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584948/how-to-create-weighted-adjacency-list-matrix-from-edge-list

Comment: Actually the problem is I dont know how to incorporate the 'Winner' into this matrix. Like for every victory, the point should go to the team who won

Comment: What sort of data so you have?  Match results?

Comment: Yes, match results.