# From (not a square) adjacency matrix to visual graph in R

Tags: r, matrix, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

We have an non square **adjacency matrix p** (197x190)[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLj2w.png) without weights (only 1 if the 2 telephone numbers have called with each other and 0 otherwise). We tried to visualize this with a graph using this simple code and the igraph package:

> p<-as.matrix(dcast(SNA_data, A_NUMBER~B_NUMBER, value.var="W", fill=0))[,] 
>   graph<-graph.adjacency(p, mode="undirected", weighted=NULL) 
>   plot(graph)

The result is a very small graph in plot that is totally unreadable [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIplV.png) anybody knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `x11()` to plot your graph in an external window :

```
library(igraph)
adjm1<-matrix(sample(0:1,1000,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.9,01)),nc=10) 
g1<-graph.adjacency(adjm1)
x11()
plot(g1)
```

Reference for the simulation : [using graph.adjacency() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332233/using-graph-adjacency-in-r)

Comment: If that not work on your matrix you should give an entire code with almost a portion of your matrix.

Comment: Error in .Call("R_igraph_graph_adjacency", adjmatrix, as.numeric(mode),  : 
  At structure_generators.c:272 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix

Comment: I added some more information in my question, hope this helps!

Comment: If I unserstand your matrix has phone numbers in column and row's IDs. As I can see in the R help,`graph.adjency`  only accept squard matrix. That's not possible that your matrix is non-squared espicially if you want to make a such graph.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is not a square, it might be worth trying an incidence matrix. By default the matrix is directed from rows to columns.

```
# create the network object
network <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(p)
network

class(network)

# plot it
plot(network)
```